# Links un-clickable in Chrome & Firefox until developer tools are opened

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm doing some consulting for a site that is about to be redone, but still has to at least partially function in the mean time. At the moment my biggest issue is that on some pages the links are not clickable in FF or Chrome when the page loads, but by some magic when I open the developer tools (f12) for either everything starts working. Additionally, when the page initially loads trying to 'inspect element' does not work properly, but it works fine after the dev tools are open. My best guess here is that there's something else on the page that's effectively 'covering up' the rest of the page, but I haven't been able to find it yet. I've tried adding a z-index and playing with positioning to no avail, so if anyone has seen this before or has any thoughts I'd be most appreciative.

https://www.petermichaelfoundation.org/events.php?title=Upcoming+Events&type=2 and https://www.petermichaelfoundation.org/news.php?title=Foundation+News&id=1 are both good examples of the problem in action.

Comment: if something's covering up everything, then right clicking/inspect element should take you right to the covering element.

Comment: What links should be clickable in the events page you listed that aren't? Seems to work fine.

Comment: There's nothing overt, and inspect element is not functioning properly on those pages either. I didn't code the site, I'm just doing some consulting/upkeep while they finalize plans for the new site; so I'm not really sure what that original dev did that migh be causing the issue. I've never come across anything like it in 7+ years.

Comment: There are 'register' links below each of the even flyer images on the event page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table containing the content has **z-index: -2**; As a result, it is being placed below the body.

Comment: That's it! I thought I'd gone through them all, but I didn't catch that. thank you so much!